# Debian and VPCS/PC can't ping [Supernetting - GNS3]

Tags: networking, ip, ping, subnet

Here my topology:

[image]

All deb and PC **can** ping each other, **except** for deb2 to PC-2 (PC-2 is inside a **supernet** with PC-1, same network, same netmask and same broadcast, different address for eth0 and eth1). Trying to ping from PC-2 to deb-2 (or from deb-2 to PC-2):

```
ping 10.0.0.2
```

It return an error:

> icmp_seq=1 timeout

Where is the problem?

Comment: Whats the port mode on the switch CD4?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5C3LifF.png

Comment: Hey, @AntoninoS were you able to solve this? I have a similar issue here, and any input would be much appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833476/aws-unable-to-ping-gns3-router-from-another-server